# Is there an altimeter API in iOS and correspondent hardware on iDevices?

Tags: ios

I would like to know if an altimeter is available on iOS, and, if not, is there a way to calculate height, with much possible accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone and 3G-enabled iPads have GPS units in them. They can use the GPS to determine current altitude along with other position and velocity variables. The API used to access this information is called CoreLocation. Specifically, you would use a CLLocationManager object to send your app CLLocation objects which contain an "altitude" property.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html

Answer (score 2):

Core Location has an `altitude` attribute There is a basic tutorial available [here](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/); note that it has multiple parts.

For the Core Location docs, check out the CLLocation Class Reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html).